# Highcharts won't draw line when series values are all 0

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts won't connect points in a line chart series if all the values in the array are 0 when a gradient is used.

Sample Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/p2EYM/20/

This seems to be related to the now closed issue [found here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1687). Does anyone know if there is there a workaround for this?

[image: With gradient applied]

[image: Without gradient applied]

```
var colors =  ['#4572A7', 
               '#AA4643', 
               '#89A54E', 
               '#80699B', 
               '#3D96AE', 
               '#DB843D', 
               '#92A8CD', 
               '#A47D7C', 
               '#B5CA92'];

 var applyGradient = function(color) {
     return { radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')]
            ]
        };
 };

//works if you comment this out.
colors = $.map(colors,  applyGradient);

$('#container').highcharts({
    colors: colors,
    title: {
        text: 'Points with zero value are not connected by line'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',
                     'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        offset: 0,
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            connectNulls: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
    },
    series: [{ data: [2, 10, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20] }, 
             { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
             ]

});
```

Comment: I changed one of the values to .01 instead of 0, and it showed a line. Not sure if you'd consider that an acceptable "workaround"

Comment: change the yAxis min to a value < 0 and check it

Comment: Example from github (http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/p2EYM/21/) seems to working fine.

Comment: For those interested, here is the response I received on Github. Basically, the workaround is to apply the colors to the markers instead of the series itself. https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2517 and http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/p2EYM/21/

Answer (score 0):

If you move the *"colors = $.map(colors,  applyGradient);"* line to after you call highcharts it should work.

```
//works if you comment this out.
colors = $.map(colors,  applyGradient);
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/jQQF5/

Comment: This doesn't work. The colors must be set before the chart is rendered . By moving the line, the colors aren't applied to the chart.

Answer (score 0):

This is 'bug' for Highcharts, and in general for SVG, see [this](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1677).